# what if i give duplicate entries in limits.conf for same parameter with a different value?

Tags: linux, limits, ulimit

I want to know if i give the following entries in /etc/security/limits.conf
which sets different limits on the OS level
which one will take effect?

*** hard nofile 8192**

*** hard nofile 65536**

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer by myself just posting it here for someone to be useful

The Value given last in the file will be taken effect
 in the above case

ulimit -Hn gives 
65336